# How to Generate a Series for Each Week between 2 Dates (1 year)

Tags: postgresql

I have a login history table in my database that records every time someone successfully logs in to my app.

I am trying to create a view that will return counts of active user logins by week (Every 7 days) from 730 days ago to 365 days ago.  Basically, 365 days before the last 365 days.  So for example, the current date is April 21, 2022.  I'd like to generate a series of integers 1-53 (53 instead of 52 because of the 1 extra day) between the dates April 21, 2020 and April 20, 2021.  Each integer represents the week number.  Because of this, simply doing a to_char on the dates with 'WW' won't work.  Bringing in the need to perform counts for each of these weeks is also a challenge, and I can't seem to figure out how to write the view query.

A very simplified version of my login history table basically looks like the following

```
 user_id | logged_in_on
---------|---------------------
 1       | 2020-04-21 13:22:14
 2       | 2020-04-21 17:38:11
 1       | 2021-04-28 16:32:21
 5       | 2021-04-18 04:33:45
```

So the results I would like the view to contain should look something like the following

```
 week | login_count
------|-------------
 1    | 2
 2    | 1
 3    | 0
 .
 .
 .
 51   | 0
 52   | 1
```

The resulting view should contain a record for each week, or period of 7 days, from 730 days ago to 365 days ago.  It doesn't necessarily have to contain week numbers.  It can also be 2 date columns that contain the start and end dates of each week.  As long as each record in the view represents a week would be fine for me to use.

Is it even possible to create a single query that's able to return this data?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The following query should generate a series of dates, each date representing the first date of each set of a week (7 days) starting from 730 days ago and ending at 365 days ago from the current date.

```
SELECT 
   to_char(i::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS week_start_date 
FROM 
   generate_series(CURRENT_DATE-INTERVAL '730 day', CURRENT_DATE-INTERVAL '365 day', '1 week') i;
```